# CSS horizontal scroll: rows style issue

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I need to implement in pure html/css an horizontal scroll area organized in rows. I need only one scroll for the whole area (no independent scroll for each row). I've tried with the following code, but the problem is that the styles of border and background for the row class are not extended like the overflow content (I want they follow the width of the content).
Any idea how to fix that?

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#scrollHorizontalContainer {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #666;
}

.row {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: #222;
}

.box {
  margin: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: mediumpurple;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollHorizontalContainer">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>  
    <div class="box"></div>  
    <div class="box"></div>  
    <div class="box"></div>  
    <div class="box"></div>   
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>  
    <div class="box"></div>  
    <div class="box"></div>  
    <div class="box"></div>  
    <div class="box"></div>  
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this somehow helps; Keep in mind that the width of row depends on how many boxes you have in there 
So you may need to change the width when you have got further more

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#scrollHorizontalContainer {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow-x: scroll;

  background-color: #666;
}

.row {    
display: block;
height: 100px;
width: 134vw;
white-space: nowrap;
border: 1px solid blue;
background-color: #222;
}

.box {
  margin: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: mediumpurple;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollHorizontalContainer">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>  
    <div class="box"></div>  
    <div class="box"></div>  
    <div class="box"></div>  
    <div class="box"></div>  
    <div class="box"></div>  
    <div class="box"></div>  
    <div class="box"></div>   
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>  
    <div class="box"></div>  
    <div class="box"></div>  
    <div class="box"></div>  
    <div class="box"></div>  
 
    <div class="box"></div>  
    <div class="box"></div>  
    <div class="box"></div> 
  </div>
  
</div>
```

I'll provide an update soon with an adapted width dynamically

Comment: Thank you! Yes I need the thing to works dynamically, since the number of the boxes can change. How can I compute the exact value of the row width (how did you compute 134 vw)?